# AS3 How do you access an instance of a class from anywhere?

Tags: actionscript-3, frameworks

I currently pass a reference to my model through the constructor to any class that needs it in my simple mvc pattern, this can get annoying at times when it starts to go deeper.

How do Classes such as [LoadMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) allow you from anywhere to simple import the class, and do something like `addChild(LoaderMax.getContent("bg"));`? Replicating this should surely be a good way to have my model work, without the complexity of big frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Statics are your friend

As previous answers have noted, [TweenLite/Max](http://www.greensock.com/) etc. makes heavy use of `static` members to get work done. This is exactly like the `Math` class, for example, and can be a very convenient design pattern. You have global access to the class, and that can definitely alleviate the issue of getting access to variables through deeply nested classes.

#### Statics are the enemy

Statics, however, bring certain problems to the table. Most importantly, they tend to reduce flexibility and modularity of classes through the often unnecessary addition of *tightly coupled relationships*. It's a bit like pouring concrete over your application. It does work, but changing behavior becomes difficult as project features change.

#### Static members != instance members

Note, very clearly, that a static member "belongs" to the class itself, and not an instance of that class. Static members have no access to instance members. This causes troubles when you want to mix these members up in logic. You tend to have to make everything static (the so-called "static-cling" effect). Static patterns are often argued to be argued to be "anti" object-oriented, for precisely this reason. Once you build a structure on a static pattern you tend to lose many of the principles that makes OOD powerful.

#### In small does, they're pretty nice

That all being said - TweenLite is a great example of a static pattern that is totally appropriate - its a utility package, one that logic is not dependent on. And that should probably be how you leverage statics, too.

To reduce reliance on statics, or even global vars, it does often mean writing more code, but the flexibility in app structure gained is often quite worth it. @Marty_Wallace has a pretty good solution imo.

#### Demeter and the Paperboy

Finally, I'll just mention the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), or the Principle of Least Knowledge, and the related [Paperboy and the Wallet](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/demeter.pdf) example, which is often pointed to in discussions of statics:

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only
>     units "closely" related to the current
>     unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

Hopefully that sheds a little bit of light on a fairly complicated and not-often obvious issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using the `static` namespace, however I discourage the use of this.

```
package
{
    public class Main
    {
        public static function sayHell():void
        {
            trace("hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

You can now call `sayHello()` like this from anywhere in the application (assuming you've imported the class).

```
Main.sayHello();
```

Another thing you can do (to make the entire class accessible from within the application) is create a static property that refers to the class itself:

```
package
{
    public class Something
    {
        public static var instance:Something;

        public function Something()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        public function someFunction():void
        {
            trace('hello!');
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can now use like so:

```
Something.instance.someFunction();
```

The only thing to note here is that you need to create an instance of `Something` for this to work to call the constructor and define `instance`.

---

### What I would do

1. Create a base class for all objects in your application
2. Create a manager class that takes care of these objects
3. Create a setter within your base class to define the manager

Here's an example:

**Base**

```
package
{
    public class Base extends Object
    {
        private var _manager:Manager;

        public function set manager(m:Manager):void
        {
            _manager = m;
            init();
        }

        protected function init():void
        {
            manager.someFunction();
        }

        public function get manager():Manager{ return _manager; }
    }
}
```

**Manager**

```
package
{
    public class Manager extends Object
    {
        public function someFunction():void
        {
            trace('hello!');
        }
    }
}
```

Now anything that extends `Base` will have access to anything held in `Manager` via the `manager` getter property. All you need to do is make sure you define the `manager`, which is easily achieved from within anything that extends `Base` like so:

```
var something:SomeExtendingClass = new SomeExtendingClass();
something.manager = manager;
```

Comment: That could work, but what about if he wants to be able to get any class? For your method to work, you will have to make every class inherit from **Base** class. Sure, you can use it as a core class for every other class, but what if he have a class inheriting from Sprite or other built-in class?

Comment: For display such as Sprites, Bitmaps, MovieClips, Videos, etc; why not have a **skin:DisplayObject** property that acts as the display for the base class? That's how I've structured the framework that I use and it works great for me..

Comment: That's a good practice, in fact I use the same strategy in my framework, but if he is already using **DisplayObject** instead of a Core class, restructuring the whole project is a pain. He will have lots of calls like **stage.addChild(myobject)** that will need to be refactored to **stage.addChild(myobject.skin)**. And is more aggravated if he use 3rd libraries like TweenMax which expects a **DisplayObject**. So I don't think is a simple solution.

Comment: In that case he could create an interface with the above methods, then create two branches of Base which implement it- DisplayBase and ObjectBase.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is just a static method, but to answer your question about a global instance of a class:

```
package myPackage
{
    public var globalVariable:MyClass = new MyClass();
}
```

You can access it with:

```
import myPackage.globalVariable;
trace(globalVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to rethink in which way you want to name your classes.

You can instantiate whatever class you want, at run-time, but to access a instance by name, you have to make changes in your structure. For example, the getContent() function you mentioned in LoaderMax, all it does is to search in an array for the given loader that matchs the name, among other things. You can read the *name* variable comment for a description.

> A name that you use to identify the loader instance. This name can be fed to the `getLoader()` or `getContent()` methods or traced at any time. Each loader's name should be unique. If you don't define one, a unique name will be created automatically, like "loader21".

So in this system, you have to name every single member (loaders in this case) if you want to be able to search them. Because if I call `getClassInstance("myinstance")`, what is "myinstance" representing? Where should I name it?

That said, **if you want to do it for DisplayObjects only**, you can use [getChildByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29). But again, you have to name every DisplayObject (just set the *name* variable).

Hope this helps.